# Convert list iterator to pointer doesn't work?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, iterator

I want to implement a function which iterates over a list and returns a pointer in case of a match. I wrote:

```
std::list<JobEntry> jobs;

JobsList::JobEntry *JobsList::getJobById(int jobId) {
    for (auto const& job : jobs) {
        if (job.pid==jobId) {
            return std::addressof(*job);
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

But this doesn't work, how can I do it?

Comment: What is `jobs`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I mentioned this and now added declaration

Comment: What is `JobEntry`? Is unary `*` operator for that defined?

Comment: You don't have an iterator; you have a value of type `JobEntry` (well, a constant reference to one), so you don't need to dereference. Your compiler probably told you just as much.

Comment: Why a pointer instead of a const reference? This is also what [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is for.

Comment: [Your code plus proper supplement can be compiled](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PJX8ppn4H9juFsp4).

Comment: can someone show me how my code will look like? I want pointer

Comment: @daniel see the answer I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getJobById()` is declared to return a pointer to a non-const `JobEntry` object, but `job` is a reference to a `const JobEntry` object. You can't assign a pointer-to-const to a pointer-to-non-const.  So drop the `const`.

Also, a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) handles iterators internally, so `job` is the actual object you want to return a pointer to, not an iterator to the object, so don't try to dereference it.

```cpp
JobsList::JobEntry* JobsList::getJobById(int jobId) {
    for (auto &job : jobs) {
        if (job.pid == jobId) {
            return std::addressof(job);
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

That being said, consider using the standard [`std::find_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm instead of a manual loop:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

JobsList::JobEntry* JobsList::getJobById(int jobId) {
    auto iter = std::find_if(jobs.begin(), jobs.end(),
        [=](const JobEntry &job) { return job.pid == jobId; }
    );
    if (iter != jobs.end())
        return std::addressof(*iter);
    return nullptr;
}
```